# Java Swing - Clicking on a shape to change its color

Tags: java, swing, shapes

I need to make a Java Swing application that displays a rectangle on screen and if it is being clicked, it should change its color to black if it's white or white if it's black. The problem is that it is a class that needs to extend JComponent and override paintComponent. I got everything done except the clicking part. For some reason I cannot make it so that it only changes colors when it is clicked. It also changes colors when the background apart from it is being clicked.

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class RectangleC extends JComponent implements MouseListener{
    private int width, height;
    private Color color;

    public RectangleC(int w, int h, Color c){
        width = w;
        height = h;
        color = c;
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        if(this.contains(e.getPoint())){
            if(color == Color.WHITE) {
                color = Color.BLACK;
            }
            else {
                color = Color.WHITE;
            }
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){};
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){};
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){};
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){};

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rectangle Component");
        RectangleC rectangle2 = new RectangleC(300, 500, Color.BLACK);
        frame.add(rectangle2);
        frame.setSize(600,600);;
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I cannot seem to get it working using the e.getPoint() method. I also tried using coordinates and e.getX() and e.getY() and that works as long as the shape is in its default position. However, if the shape is being moved to the center, it does no longer work.

Here is the method that I tried:

```
    @Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    int currentX = e.getX();
    int currentY = e.getY();
    if(currentX > this.getX() && currentX < this.getX() + width && currentY > this.getY() && currentY < this.getY() + height ){        
        if(color != Color.WHITE)
            color = Color.WHITE;
        else
            color = Color.black;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

How can I make it so that it only changes colors when it is clicked? I am really out of ideas and I could not find any way to do this.

Comment: Are you sure that your updated function isn't working as I tried it and is working absolutely fine and the color is changing only when you click on rectangle and not on the background

Comment: Based on your current code, when ever you receive a `mouseClicked` event, `contains` will always be true - as the event occurs within the component. My personal though is you're doing it the wrong way, and extending a component in this way for this purpose might not be the best result

Comment: @MadProgrammer The school assignment requires it that way, it is not up to me.

Comment: @AndreiRosu For me, I'd still consider using `java.awt.Rectangle` to mange the actual functionality, since it already has a `contains` method and can be painted, but that's me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems the code shared above is fine with a small issue that you are taking x and y of the `component` instead of the `Rectangle` painted on `Component` while comparing in `mousePressed`. So what you can do is create two functions to return x and y of `rectangle` and then use those functions where ever you need to check the coordinates of rectangle.

Please find the updated code below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class RectangleC extends JComponent implements MouseListener{
    private int width, height;
    int x,y;
    private Color color;

    public RectangleC(int w, int h, Color c){
        width = w;
        height = h;

        //Given x and y some default position. This can be changed as required
        x = 20;
        y = 20;

        color = c;
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        int currentX = e.getX();
        int currentY = e.getY();
        if(currentX > this.getRectX() && currentX < this.getRectX() + width && currentY > this.getRectY() && currentY < this.getRectY() + height ){        
            if(color != Color.WHITE)
                color = Color.WHITE;
            else
                color = Color.black;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    // Function to return rectangle coordinate
    private int getRectX() {
        return this.getX()+x;
    }


    private int getRectY() {
        return this.getY()+y;
    }
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){};
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){};
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){};
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){};

    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rectangle Component");
        RectangleC rectangle2 = new RectangleC(300, 500, Color.BLACK);
        frame.add(rectangle2);
        frame.setSize(600,600);;
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that it works this way. However, if I create an array of rectangles and display, for example, 2 of them, only the first one changes colors. Do you know any way to fix this?

Comment: @AndreiRosu In that case, you have to maintain x and y array for each rectangle and then use function by passing rectangle index

Comment: I modified the constructor to be able to take the x and y position, but whenever I add two components to the JFrame, only one comes up. I tried using JPanel as well but it does not work. Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: Please share what you have tried and I will be happy to help you for further questions. Also, ensure you are using layouts as that will help you to properly align rectangles

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QuMApU3F -> I tried this. I made it so it prints the coordinates of the corner of the rectangles to make sure that they are right, and they are. It should work but it does not. When I click on the second rectangle, nothing happens.